# Location of the Styled, unstyled Error for Apex:Messages, How to change the content?

Tags: apex, visualforce, error

We have a form on our system that has some required fields. And one of the things that is required is a check box. If you don't fill out the fields it will show you an error message that says "you need this field" but if you fill out all the boxes and don't check the checkbox it will come up with this error message.

[image: This is what we get if we fill the information without checking the box.]

Here is the code for the checkbox and the field below it.

```
 <div class="form-group required checkbox">
        <label>
             <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Service_Order__c.Accept_Terms_Conditions__c}" /> I accept the <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#termsModal">terms and conditions</a> of this order.
        </label>
 </div>        


  <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group required col-xs-12">
          <label for="project-name">Project name</label>
                <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-keyboard-o"></i></span>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!Service_Order__c.Name}" required="true" styleClass="form-control" />
                    </div>
              </div>
```

We also have this piece of code for the apex messages.

```
 <apex:pageMessages id="styledError"/>
 <apex:messages id="unstyledError"/>



public class force_NewOrderLogic {



          ApexPages.StandardController stdController;
          public force_NewOrderLogic(ApexPages.StandardController con){
              stdController = con;
          }

public PageReference saveAndRedirect() {
  if(stdController.save() != null) {
    PageReference redirectPage = Page.force_OrderDetail;
    redirectPage.setRedirect(true);
    redirectPage.getParameters().put('id',stdController.getId());
    redirectPage.getParameters().put('msg','new-record-added');
    return redirectPage;
  } return null;
}

}




public class calypso_new_orderlogic {


          ApexPages.StandardController stdController;
          public calypso_new_orderlogic(ApexPages.StandardController con){
              stdController = con;
          }

public PageReference saveAndRedirect(){
  try{
    PageReference redirectPage = Page.force_OrderDetail;
    redirectPage.setRedirect(true);
    redirectPage.getParameters().put('id',stdController.getId());
    redirectPage.getParameters().put('msg','new-record-added');
    return redirectPage;
  }catch(Exception ex){
         ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'The terms and conditions must be accepted'));
}return null;
}
}
```

// EDIT, i've tried those two methods none of them work

Comment: so @Greg exactly what do want can you explain bit more so i can understand?

Comment: I just want to get rid of the message below "The terms and conditions must be accepted "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page messages are set in a controller using the ApexPages class. See here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_ApexPages_methods.htm

You can add a validation in the save method of your controller to show an error message before the record is saved. If you are using a standard controller, you can use a controller extension to override the save method and do the same thing.

The save method in your controller would look something like this:

```
        public void save() {
            if (!Service_Order__c.Accept_Terms_Conditions__c) {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'The terms and conditions must be accepted'));
            } else { 
                insert Sevice_Order__c;
            }
        }
```